# How to specify NIntegrate to include a specific set of points

Tags: numerical-integration

My function has a very narrow peak that NIntegrate function misses . Currently I am using MinRecursion=100 option to deal with that but it makes the integration very slow. Is there any way I can specify the peak position to the NIntegrate function?

```
Dcompound[Tobs_?NumericQ, \[Lambda]c_, t0_, sd_] := 
  NIntegrate[CompoundFun[t, Tobs, \[Lambda]c, t0, sd], {t, 0, Tobs}, 
    MinRecursion -> 100, MaxRecursion -> Infinity]
```

[Example of pathological function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#8354729)

Comment: Please include code. A minimal example that illustrates your problem. No screenshots please.

Comment: Without the definition of `CompoundFun` we cannot execute your code.

Comment: Really simple dumb easy way. You know your function is "nice" everywhere except near the narrow sharp peak. So do three `NIntegrate`, one from zero to the lower edge of the peak, one from the lower to upper edges of the peak and a third from the upper edge of the peak to Tobs. And add those three results. By making that middle one narrow and ONLY capturing that peak should make it recognize and adapt to that peak and be fast by not requiring vast numbers of recursion or precision.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := Sech[10*(x - 1/5)]^2 + Sech[100*(x - 2/5)]^4 + 
  Sech[1000*(x - 3/5)]^6
```

For comparison, the exact integral is

```
int = Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] // Simplify

(* (1/15000)(-14 + 1500 (Tanh[2] + Tanh[8]) - 
  50 (-3 Tanh[40] + Tanh[40]^3 - 3 Tanh[60] + Tanh[60]^3) + 15 Tanh[400] + 
  15 Tanh[600]) *)

int // N

(* 0.210803 *)
```

The numeric integral is

```
{t1, intN1} =
 NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1},
   MinRecursion -> 2,
   WorkingPrecision -> 15] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.009101, 0.209736068835675} *)
```

The relative error is

```
(intN1 - int)/int

(* -0.005060022880354 *)
```

Determine where critical points occur in the integrand and include the locations in the integration path

```
iter = {x, 0, NSolveValues[{f'[x] == 0, 0 < x < 1}, x], 1} // Flatten

(* {x, 0, 0.2, 0.380047, 0.399966, 0.597268, 0.6, 1} *)

{t2, intN2} = NIntegrate[f[x], iter,
   MinRecursion -> 2,
   WorkingPrecision -> 15] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.021666, 0.210802735181435} *)
```

The relative error is greatly reduced

```
(intN2 - int)/int

(* -1.513804*10^-9 *)
```

There is a increase in time due to additional evaluations

```
t2/t1

(* 2.38062 *)
```

Comment: This `NIntegrate[f,{x,x1,...,x7}]` syntax seems very useful. In your example it seems to give the same result as
`NIntegrate[f,{x,x1,x2}] + ... + NIntegrate[f,{x,x6,x7}]`. According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html), this syntax can be used to specify the location of singularities.

Comment: @user293787 - while Mma is testing for singularities at those points it is evaluating the function there. This insures that the integral is evaluated in their vicinity.